# TypeScript yells "Cannot find module '@angular/platform-server'" in Angular Universal 16. Why?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I have installed Angular Universal on my app by running `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` and when I open `src/app/app.config.server.ts` file in my VSCode, TypeScript yells the following error:

> Cannot find module '@angular/platform-server' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Though I already have installed `@angular/platform-server` package. I mean it will be installed automatically when we call `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` command! So what can be the problem?

Here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "universal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run universal:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/universal/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run universal:server",
    "prerender": "ng run universal:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^16.2.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^16.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: check your `node_modules`, is it present ?

Comment: "I mean it will be installed automatically when we call `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` command!" The way that sentence is phrased implies that that command has not been called. If it has been called, I would [edit] it to say "It was installed automatically when I called the  `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` command."

Comment: @heretic Yes, it was installed automatically :)
@Matthieu Yes, it's present in `node_modules` folder. I am using `pnpm`, is it because of that maybe?!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I found out, there was a problem with the VSCode maybe! When you use the `pnpm` package manager and add an external library to your project, some of your files get modified automatically by the Angular CLI. Then when you open the modified files that are importing some of newly installed modules, then VSCode gives an unnecessarily error that says it cannot find the module in your `node_modules` folder! But if you re-type the import path, the error simply goes away! So although it was stupid, but there was nothing to be worry about!